# cat: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: bash, shell, sh, databricks, databricks-notebook

I am using `cat` command to merge multiple files using `%sh` command in Azure Databricks Notebook. I have around 1200 csv files in the `data_files` folder and the total size of files are around 300 GB. When I run the below code, sometimes it is merging the files without any errors, but sometimes it throws the error `cat: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable` and the `output.txt` file is created with no data.

```
err=$(cat /dbfs/mnt/devl/header_file/*.csv /dbfs/mnt/devl/data_files/*.csv 2>&1 > /dbfs/mnt/devl/output.txt)
RC=$?
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Error code : $RC"
  echo "Error msg : $err"
fi
```

Can anyone tell what is the rootcause of the error `cat: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable` and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should include a reference to your previous question on this topic. These issues seem related, are they? Did it stop working, or did the accepted solution ever work? Is `/dbfs/mnt/devl` a remote or local machine? If local, is it in your laptop or mounting from a network location. If network location, what sort of hardware and network configuration? Good luck.

Comment: That's weird. That error is `EAGAIN`, which occurs when a call would block, but the file handle was marked as non-blocking.

Comment: Hi Shellter. The question that i asked had a different purpose. In that question, I was asking why I was not able to see the error message in the `err` variable. But in this question, my question is to find out the root cause of the `cat: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable` error. The intention is these two questions are entirely different. Even Stackoverflow also suggest to ask separate question if the context of questions are different @shellter

Comment: [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: @SarathSubramanian : Yes, I agree and salute your posting 2 separate questions. Now include some information about the file-system you are writing that file to. Intermittent failures usually mean a networked file system, but you'll have to give us some details. Good luck.

Comment: @ikegami is right, in your case, the `EAGAIN (35)` comes with `nonblocking` mode IO, but `cat` and `sh` works on `blocking` mode, so your error is weird ; by the way, what do you mean by `%sh` that sounds like `Microsoft-made-unix-shell` or something like ?